# Create method inside another method

Tags: python, class, methods

This isn't really a problem, but I just came to a situation were i thought I might create a method inside another method.

In the real class I have over 15 methods so i don't want to create another one for just one use-case => plot a special kind of data.
So I created a method inside a method. It works but I want to know if its a common thing or if it is bad programming.

I know that i could use list and for-loops instead, but I somehow like this solution.

```py
class ExampleClass:
    def method_1(self, some, parameter):
        # Some calculation to get different datasets
        def plot_data(data, title):
            plt.plot(data)
            plt.title(title)
            plt.show()

        plot_data(dataset_1, title="Plot 1")
        plot_data(dataset_2, title="Plot 2")
        plot_data(dataset_3, title="Plot 3")
```

Comment: Absolutely nothing wrong with this.

Comment: Definitely not a bad thing - in fact I wish more people would do this. Without nested functions we wouldn't have decorators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this, this is called a **nested function**. The inner function is able to access the variables within the enclosing scope.

Comment: Ah okay thanks for the information. Never heard pf nested functions,